# How do I get a webpage title from an sql database with flask and jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a table where I store the title of a webpage. I have created a function in python that returns the title as a string. In jinja how exactly can I access that function? I don't want to pass the title through at every endpoint.

```
def create_title():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT description FROM settings"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

```
<title>{{ create_title() }}</title>
```

And I would like to do something like this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `render_template` function call from the flask route must tell the template what functions or variables it has access to. It will not inherit every function name in the Python code

You should also consider adding exception handling in case the connection / query fails. Otherwise, you'll get `None` returned as the title, or cause internal server error

Answer (score 0):

here is how you do it:

```
@app.route('<Your route>')
def index():
    return render_template('<your_html_filename>.html', create_title=create_title)
```